# ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

I have a Django cookiecutter template. After performing all the required actions given on cookiecutter docs when I run `python manage.py migrate` I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\task_manager_app\manage.py", line 31, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1303, in check
    *cls._check_indexes(databases),
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1695, in _check_indexes
    connection.features.supports_covering_indexes or
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\features.py", line 93, in is_postgresql_11
    return self.connection.pg_version >= 110000
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 329, in pg_version
    with self.temporary_connection():
  File "C:\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 603, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 199, in connect
    conn_params = self.get_connection_params()
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Tiwari\Desktop\My_Projects\GDC\GDC-Level-10-Milestone-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 157, in get_connection_params
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value.
```

This is the settings base.py file (database setting part) which come by default with template

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": env.db(
        "DATABASE_URL",
        default="postgres://localhost/task_manager_app",
    ),
}
DATABASES["default"]["ATOMIC_REQUESTS"] = True
```

I've set the database URL using command

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:mypass@127.0.0.1:5432/task_manager_app
```

Anyone help me out to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to do it as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql', #Make sure you have psycopg2 installed. It is postgresql connector. 
       'NAME': ‘DB NAME’,
       'USER': 'DB USERNAME',
       'PASSWORD': 'USER PASSWORD',
       'HOST': 'HOST IP',
       'PORT': 'PORT',#Generally 5432
   }
}
```

Comment: django cookiecutter didn't implement the database setting as you told. It generates the name, engine, port using the database url.

Answer (score 0):

After puzzling over it a lot, I got the solution. The problem was having the character "#" in my database password.